# Microwave absorption in tissue

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Why do I have a big microwave absorption in tissue, when the tissue conductivity is high? I thougt the opposite would be correct. Can somebody explain the reason?

Comment: 1st define "microwave"! Ever heard of frequency? 2nd who says/writes that absoption is higher in "high" conductivity tissue?

Comment: 1. For a mircowave with 2 GHz. 2. I can't write who said this.

Comment: So its just an assumption of You? You should ask if this is right, not for explanation of a wrong assumption.

Comment: This was a phrase of my boss. But I won't ask him about this. :)

Comment: This is wrong. Aqueous ions are too heavy to move at such high frequencies. Only exeption is H+, but protons are rare in tissue, (living) tissue has to be almost neutral (to be alive). Mechanism of microwave (>1 GHz) absorption is by relaxation of orientational polarisation, very specific for water.

Comment: All you need to absorb any radio energy is to be a large-enough antenna. All you need to be an antenna is to be conductive. No problem - you're full of salt water.

Comment: @Georg: you should put your comment as the answer. There is also the issue that the conductivity of the tissue makes bulk absorption if there is no significant reflection, and the strong absorption of water.

Comment: ""if there is no significant reflection, and the strong absorption of water. "" and anybody knowing Fresnels formulas knows about the connection between absorption an reflection.

Comment: @Georg:  you can have absorption with zero reflection if the conductivity rises slowly and smoothly compared to the wavelength.

Comment: ""if the conductivity rises slowly and smoothly compared to the wavelength."" Which is a well known property of tissue :=)

Comment: @Georg: it is a well known property of tissue, the skin is not conductive, and the conductivity rise slowly.

Comment: Ah, skin is not conductive! That is why electric chair is popular un US? This silly "discussion" becomes boring. You are one of those "always right" people?

Comment: @Georg: your deep knowledge, helpful answers and insightful ideas would be more appreciated if you could stay less personal in your comments. And I'll be happy to upvote your answer to this question, since I (and I think that others too) find it very useful.

Comment: @Slaviks look for "microwave" in this forum. The first 4 entries show a lot on the topic, including answers from me. The distinction between orientational polarisation and rotation is hard to understand, it seems. That the usual "conductivty ingredients" do not play a role at MW frequencies is basic knowledge in PC.

Comment: @Georg: Skin is not conductive compared to deep tissue--- you can still electrocute people, because current distributes itself over the whole flesh. The conductivity rises in proportion to the fluid content of the tissue. Also, I find that when I am wrong, it is a good day, because it is when I learn something.

Answer (score -2):

If you are referring to the microwave Ovens then this might be the possible reason,

Microwave Oven are basically meant to cook food i.e. water rich food. So anything which has a high content of water effectively absorbs microwave radiation and get hot.

EDIT1: for details on how microwave works..[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven#Principles)

Now, since tissue contains water the above statements might hold.

NOTE : The Diagram was useless..I realised it much later... :( deleted for everyone's sake..

Comment: Interesting IR/vis/uv spec of ??? (water?) but not relevant at microwave oven frequencies ( about 12 cm wavelength). Did You realize that the spectrum starts at 10 inverse centimeters, which is a frequency measure?

Comment: this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: That diagram is not useless! You might use it in case somebody asks why thick layers of water are blue.

Comment: @Georg: I mean for the topic in question...

Answer (score -2):

You can read the wikipedia (the link already mentioned), it describes the process called *Dielectric heating*.

The matter of conductivity of the organic tissue is tricky. For instance, the water is a dielectric, it consists of polarized H2O molecules, all the electrons are tightly bound. However when there are minerals dissolved in the water it's a conductor - due to the ions.

So the the "non-pure" water is being heated by oscillating EM field, although it's a conductor practically.

Comment: -1 for rechurning a partly wrong Wiki page. MW and water is not dielectic heating!

Comment: @Georg: Well, this is exactly what wiki says, MW targets mostly liquid water. Do you disagree or what?

Comment: So read Your answer! ""So the the "non-pure" water is being heated by oscillating EM field, although it's a conductor practically."" This shows You did not understand.

Comment: @Greg: I'm starting to dislike your tone. Do you think I have to prove you that I realize what I write, hoping to earn your invaluable upvote? Also your comments about down-voting because of "rechurning a partly wrong Wiki page" are inapplicable. Have comments/objections regarding the subject? Fine. Criticism is welcome, when it's justified. I think I **do** understand (at least in general) how induced dipole interacts with an oscillating EM field. Don't believe me? Fine, I don't insist. But this is not related to the subject.